# jstl parse error: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Unrecognized object supplied as 'xml' attribute to parse

Tags: java, xml, jsp, jstl

I have a valid string of xml on a jsp(portlet version 1) project.

I am trying to use jstl tags to parse through it.
Included tag libs:

```
    <%@ page import="javax.portlet.*"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet" prefix="portlet"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

Currently I set the string:

```
String activexml = (String)renderRequest.getPortletSession().getAttribute("activexml");
```

Then I set my attribute for the jsp page:

```
pageContext.setAttribute("activexml", activexml);
```

This is all working, here comes the error. When I go to set the xml to be parsed. The C tag is good, no error comes back there, but the x receives the error:

```
<c:set var="active-xml" scope="session" value="${activexml}"/>
<x:parse xml="${active-xml}" var="active"/>
```

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Unrecognized object supplied as 'xml' attribute to parse

I have local copies of standard.jar and jstl.jar in my project. Any help would be most appreciated, I think it is either my syntax, or I am missing some project setup jars or something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in the declared variable name.

```
<c:set var="active-xml" ... />
```

Like in Java, the hyphen is in EL interpreted as subtraction operator. The `${active-xml}` will basically give you the result of `${active}` minus `${xml}`.

Use an underscore instead.

```
<c:set var="active_xml" ... />
```

Or, just love Java code conventions a bit more and use camel case.

```
<c:set var="activeXml" ... />
```

Or, just use the original value right away without copying it via `<c:set>`.

```
<x:parse xml="${activexml}" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks, trying this now